# Bluetooth Serial Port Permission Error Errno::EACCES [Ruby] [Serialport gem]

Tags: ruby, windows, bluetooth, serial-port

So I am trying to send data to my Arduino through a HC-05 Bluetooth Chip. I'm using Ruby, and so far, I get the error shown below. Any idea why? I'm using Windows 10

My arduino is on COM3 (USB) and the bluetooth chip is on COM37

**Error 1**

```
in `create': Permission denied - \\.\COM37 (Errno::EACCES)
```

If I try it again I get this error:

**Error 2**

```
in `create': Invalid argument - \\.\COM37 (Errno::EINVAL)
```

**Ruby Code**

```
require 'serialport'
puts "What COM Port?"
comport = gets.chomp
comport = comport.to_i
comport = comport -1
sp =  SerialPort.new(comport,9600)
while 1
  puts "What message do you want to send?"
  write = gets.chomp
  if write == "exit"
    abort
  end
  sp.write write
end
```

**Arduino Code**

```
#include <Motor.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

Motor m8(8);
SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(12, 13); //12-TX 13-RX
// Declare a new 'char' or "character" that we will use to store the keyboard
// input sent to the bluetooth chip
char input;
boolean stop = false;
void setup() {
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);
  m8.attach();
}

void loop() {
  // If there is input available on the bluetooth chip (that is, we sent a    character
  // to the chip from the computer)...
  if (Bluetooth.available()) {
    // Read the first available character from the bluetooth chip and store it in the
    // 'input' variable
    input = Bluetooth.read();
    if (input == 'w') {
      stop != stop;
    }
    if (input == 'd') {
      m8.turn(100);
    }
    if (input == 'a') {
      m8.turn(-100);
    }
  }
  if (stop != true) {
    m8.stop();
  }
}
```

**If I try to connect to my arduino using COM3 and USB, I don't get an error and it successfully sends data the the arduino.**

Thanks in advance!